# is there a way to make MenuItem of navDrawer not visible for non admin users? JetPack Compose Philipp Lackner tutorial

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am following Philipp Lackner's video about the navigation drawer

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLICaBEiJS0&t=215s&ab_channel=PhilippLackner

I need some of the items
to be visible and clickable only for Admin user

I need help figuring out how to solve this syntax problem

is there a way to make MenuItem of navDrawer not visible for non admin users?

[image]

this is the complete code to simulate the problem

```
package com.example.politi_cal.screens.NavDrawer


import android.graphics.Color.alpha
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.*
import androidx.compose.material.rememberScaffoldState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.alpha
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.politi_cal.Screen
import com.example.politi_cal.screens.voting_screen.SwipeScreen
import com.example.politi_cal.userCollectionRef
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


val commentsAlpha = if (isAdmin()) 1f else 0f


@Composable
fun DrawerHeader() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            //.height(200.dp)
            //.background(Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 64.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Header", fontSize = 60.sp, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun DrawerBody(
    items: List<MenuItem>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    itemTextStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp),
    onItemClick: (MenuItem) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier) {
        items(items) { item ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable { onItemClick(item) }
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    if(item.title == "Admin Only") {
                        .alpha(commentsAlpha)
                    },

            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.contentDescription)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(
                    text = item.title,
                    //modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), style = itemTextStyle

                )
            }
        }
    }

}

// the drawer TopBar should get the navController as a parameter ,
// and the composable screen function that it needs to draw after the drawer
@Composable
fun DrawerTopBar(navController: NavController, auth : FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()  , screen: @Composable (navController: NavController) -> Unit) {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Scaffold(

        drawerGesturesEnabled = scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            AppBar(onNavigationIconClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                }

            })
        },
        drawerContent = {
            DrawerHeader()
            DrawerBody(items = listOf(
                MenuItem(
                    id = "swipe",
                    title = "Swipe",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Swipe screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Home
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "settings",
                    title = "Settings",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Settings screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Settings
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "celeb profile",
                    title = "Celeb Profile",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Celeb profile screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Info
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "user profile",
                    title = "User Profile",
                    contentDescription = "Go to User profile screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.AccountBox
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "add celeb",
                    title = "Add Celeb",
                    contentDescription = "Go to User profile screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Add
                ),

                MenuItem(
                    id = "admin analytics",
                    title = "Admin Analytics",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Admin Analytics screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.MoreVert
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "logout",
                    title = "Logout",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Logout screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.ExitToApp
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    id = "admin only",
                    title = "Admin only",
                    contentDescription = "Go to Admin Only screen",
                    icon = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                )

            ), onItemClick = {
                when (it.id) {
                    "swipe" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.SwipeScreen.route)
                    }
                    "settings" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.PreferenceScreen.route)
                    }
                    "celeb profile" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.CelebProfileScreen.route)
                    }
                    "user profile" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.UserProfileScreen.route)
                    }
                    "add celeb" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.AddCelebScreen.route)
                    }
                    "admin analytics" -> {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.AdminAnalyticsScreen.route)
                    }
                    "logout" -> {
                        auth.signOut()
                        navController.navigate(Screen.LoginScreen.route)
                    }
                    "admin only" -> {
                        // check that the user is admin
                        // if not, show a message
                        // if yes, navigate to the admin only screen
                        if(isAdmin()){
                            navController.navigate(Screen.AdminOnlyScreen.route)
                        }
                        else{
                            // show a message
                            Toast.makeText(context, "You are not an admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        }

                    }
                }
            })

        }) {

        screen(navController = navController)

    }
}


fun isAdmin():Boolean{
    

}
```

MenuItem.kt

```
package com.example.politi_cal.screens.NavDrawer

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector

data class MenuItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val contentDescription: String
)
```

```
package com.example.politi_cal.screens.NavDrawer

import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Menu
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import com.example.politi_cal.R


@Composable
fun AppBar(
    onNavigationIconClick: () -> Unit
) {
    TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = onNavigationIconClick) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Menu, contentDescription = "Toggle drawer Menu")
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting there?

Comment: Why are you adding the `admin only` `MenuItem` to your list unconditionally if you want to only conditionally add it?

Comment: Have you tried to filter the list before passing it to the `Items()`?

Comment: i dont know how to if there is a filter function in kotlin to filter before adding it to the list but I was able to solve the problem because you guys helped me think more clearly I will now answer my own question

Comment: please upvote me if you think i did a good solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like recommended in the comments i took the list of menu items and created a variable to store it

then I changed the type of the list to ***mutable*** list of

because I needed the list to be able to add menu items to it if the function isAdmin return true

then I just run an if the do call the isAdmin()
if return true I now can add the menuItem acordinally

this is the solution code

```
var menuContent = mutableListOf(
        MenuItem(
            id = "swipe",
            title = "Swipe",
            contentDescription = "Go to Swipe screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.Home
        ), MenuItem(
            id = "settings",
            title = "Settings",
            contentDescription = "Go to Settings screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.Settings
        ), MenuItem(
            id = "celeb profile",
            title = "Celeb Profile",
            contentDescription = "Go to Celeb profile screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.Info
        ), MenuItem(
            id = "user profile",
            title = "User Profile",
            contentDescription = "Go to User profile screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.AccountBox
        ), MenuItem(
            id = "add celeb",
            title = "Add Celeb",
            contentDescription = "Go to User profile screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.Add
        ),

        MenuItem(
            id = "admin analytics",
            title = "Admin Analytics",
            contentDescription = "Go to Admin Analytics screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.MoreVert
        ), MenuItem(
            id = "logout",
            title = "Logout",
            contentDescription = "Go to Logout screen",
            icon = Icons.Default.ExitToApp
        )
    )

    if (isAdmin()){
        // add the ,
        // MenuItem(
        //            id = "admin only",
        //            title = "Admin only",
        //            contentDescription = "Go to Admin Only screen",
        //            icon = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
        //        )
        menuContent.add(
             MenuItem(
                        id = "admin only",
                        title = "Admin only",
                        contentDescription = "Go to Admin Only screen",
                        icon = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                    )
        )
    }


  DrawerBody(items = ***menuContent***, onItemClick = { .....




fun isAdmin(): Boolean {
    return true

}
```